# Proving the product of any # of commutators can be written as an "extended commutator" (commutator of 3+ elements)

Tags: group-theory

Suppose G is a group and as per usual, the commutator is $[g,h] := ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ for $g,h \in G$.

I need to show that the product of any number of commutators can be written in the following defined form:

$g_1 \cdot g_2 \cdot \dots \cdot g_n \cdot g_1^{-1} \cdot g_2^{-1} \cdot \dots \cdot g_n^{-1}$ where all $g_i \in G$ for $1 \geq i \geq n$

Every identity I know with commutators uses 2-3 elements (and their inverses), so I'm having trouble proving this since the starting point I'm at involves 4 elements that are not necessarily related. I figured the best thing to do would be to use induction but for the base case I have, for example,
$[g_1,g_2][g_3,g_4]=(g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1})(g_3g_4g_3^{-1}g_4^{-1})$ and I can't seem to manipulate that in anyway.